# Algunos datos del request no son mapeados

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

Envio el siguiente Request

```
{
    "name":"juan",
    "lastname":"caviedes",
    "email":"jc97@gmail.com",
    "password":"12345678q",
    "areaid":"13",
    "profileid":"2"
}
```

Tengo la clase para mapear el objeto.

```
     public class SingUpRequest {
      private String name;
      private String lastname;
      private String email;
      private String password;
      private String areaid;
      private String profileid;

      public String getAreaid(){
         return  areaid;
      }

      public void setAreaid(String areaid) {
        this.areaid = areaid;
      }

      public String getProfileid(){
      return profileid;
      }

      public void setProfileid(String profileid) {
        this.profileid = profileid;
      }
      //geters and setters
     }
```

El metodo del controller

```
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody 
    SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {}
```

> ERROR:
>
> Realizando el Debug areaid y profileid toman valores diferentes.

[image: Debug img]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner los *getters* y los *setters*? El "mapeo" de datos a beans se suele hacer mediante los nombres de los métodos (no de las variables), por lo que si los nombres de éstos son incorrectos puede no reconocerlos.

Comment: @theboshy why did the object isn't map out?

Comment: @SJuan76 estos son los getters y los setters [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201733/algunos-datos-del-request-no-son-mapeados)

Comment: A veces también pasa que pones un *setter* (o un *getter*) para una variable y con el "copiar y pegar" te olvidas de cambiar el atributo que actualizas o lees (ahem, `setProfileid()`) :-P. Pero al menos los nombres son correctos :-D.

Comment: le pusiste un breakpoint en los geters y seters de areaid y profile id? y ver que hace en el seteo?

Comment: Veo que en la imagen que pones, al debuggear signUpRequest tienes el atributo de 'username', pero en la clase de mapeo no aparece ese atributo. Es seguro que estés lanzando contra ese servicio, o lanzando esa petición? Has podido equivocarte?